# CentOS Webserver: Best practice for creating SSH user that is friendly with Nginx

Tags: linux, apache, ssh, nginx, centos

I have been looking for the past hour and I just can't understand why this isn't more straight forward. I just spun up a VPS. I have LEMP running no problem. Trying to keep with the best practices so instead of using root for my Git deployments, SFTP, etc. I've created "website" as an SSH user.

All of the files are nginx:nginx, however after several modifications to /etc/passwd and /etc/group I'm still unable to successfully ssh in with "website" and mv or modify files. I have no trouble viewing them.

Typing "groups nginx" reveals nginx:nginx.
Typing "groups website" reveals website:nginx.

Please, someone tell me what I am doing wrong. I believe the same scenario applies to Apache configurations.

Comment: It appears that changing the permissions of all files in the web directory to website:nginx may be a possible solution. I'm having to revert my group settings.

Comment: Could you add the file permissions on a file that you are not able to move/modify (using `ls -l`)?

Comment: I actually just tried chown -R website:nginx while as root and then sudo but it won't change. I don't know what gives.

Comment: root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
nginx:x:498:499:Nginx web server:/var/lib/nginx:/sbin/nologin
website:x:498:499:SFTP User:/usr/share/nginx/html:/bin/bash

Comment: Do you have setfacl/getfacl?

Comment: @JonLin I have not set that up. Let me try to simplify things. I deleted "website". I created user "webadmin" and I was able to chmod the web files to webadmin:nginx. However, if I SSH in as webadmin I still can't move or edit files inside the web root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify File Access Control. Try these commands by swapping out bob with your specific user and specific path to your web root. That way your newly created user will have to ability to read/write/execute files without the need to modify permissions.

```
setfacl -R -d -m u:bob:rwx /var/www/mydomain.com 
setfacl -R -m u:bob:rwx /var/www/mydomain.com
```

Here is further reading if you would like to know more.

http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/setfacl1.html

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Sure did! :D You wouldn't believe how much of a headache that caused. Thanks mate.

Comment: I executed the same command in centos but i am getting something like `operation not permitted`. what is the reason behind it